# HyperLedger Fabric Java SDK - ChainCode Sample in java rather than Go?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Hi  I am using Fabric Java SDK and able to run the EndToEndIT.java test cases . 
The test file loads chaincode as **example_cc.go**
I want the chaincode as **example_cc.java** and load the chaincode as java file rather than go

I am stuck and not sure how to do this . I want to know the equivalent **java** code for the **go** chaincode and a way to call it in the EndToEndIT.java test file

Please list out the steps to run the same . Thanks !

Comment: Just want to clarify . The Chain code is in go programming language , i want the equivalent java chaincode . And a way to invoke it from the endtoend test file . Please find the source in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an example from https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/java/src/main/java/example/Example.java
Gives a version of chaincode in java
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java). It contains multiple examples using maven and gradle.